# Should global variables be passed onto subroutines as arguments if they won't change?

Tags: perl, language-agnostic

I have a globally defined hash reference whose values will not ever change after being added. Thus, subroutines will not modify the hash, only access it.

Should I be passing the hash reference to subroutines that will make use of its values, or should the subroutines reference the global variable itself?

Also, it's probably bad practice to have a scaler variable for relevant values of the hash defined in the subroutines for readability (to avoid the long $hash_ref->{"abc"} syntax, using instead $abc) ?

Thanks. I am asking because I want to avoid things that would cause my code to become messy and redundant.

Comment: re. the language-agnostic tag.  I'd give a different answer for Forth, or for a language otherwise similar to Perl but which lacks `local()` and `package` and other ways to deal with 'global' variables.  And for a language without references, it may not be as obvious that there's no copying going on in `my $hashref = $big{long}{long}{hash}{lookup}; $hashref->{shorter} = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that depends, doesn't it? If your script will only ever be used with this particular data, it doesn't much matter. If you want to be able to change the data easily, passing the data to the subroutine is the way to go.

Ideally, I would personally prefer encapsulation for everything except constants. For example:

```
my $NORTH = 0;
my $SOUTH = 1;               # constants

my $db = loadstuff("file");  # interchangeable data source
dostuff($db);

sub dostuff {
    my $db = shift;
    ... # do stuff
}
```

That way, if I read the code afterwards, I can see the subroutine call `dostuff($db)`, and I don't have to go chase around to see where `$db` comes from. I can also rely on `$db` staying constant within this subroutine: encapsulated.

It is perfectly fine to make temporary copies of variables for the sake of readability, for example:

```
my $foo = $someref->{"foo"}[0];
my $bar = $someref->{"bar"}[0];
```

But be aware that changes to copies do not affect the original, of course. If you want that, you need to alias the variables, or use references.

Answer (score 3):

It makes very little difference.

- Pro:

  - It's obvious the sub uses the data.
- Con:

  - Lots of needless typing.

Global variables (file-scoped lexicals) for global data is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the hash every time can soothe any nervousness you have about 'global data'.  This can also make for more natural passing of hashes other than the one global hash.  And in code where you do sometimes pass the global hash and sometimes pass other hashes, requiring the argument (as opposed to having "have I been passed a hashref?  no?  Then I'll use the global one." logic in your subroutines) can make it easier to find those invocations that specifically make use of the global hash.

Dealing in intermediate references can make it more confusing when you want to search your code for use of the global hash.  Previously you could search for the name of the hash and find every use; now you must also search more localized parts of your code for use of the intermediate refs.   OTOH, they can certainly make for cleaner code.

So, uh, it depends.  Pick a path and, if it comes to annoy you, pick another.